# Windows 10 reinstall - what about secondary harddrives?

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation, reinstall

My current OS installation is a Win 7 which has been updated to 8.0 then to 8.1 and now updated to 10. Time has come to make a clean Win 10 install.

I've just downloaded https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 and I'm stuck on the "Choose what to keep" screen.

It doesn't provide any information about what happens to my secondary harddrives that store all my data (the C:\ drive only contains the OS. I've moved user folders, apps and other stuff to other drives).

My gut feeling is that those drives will be left untouched by choosing "Nothing" but I would like to get some confirmation on that one before I continue.

Comment: Windows installers have only ever modified the system drive.  If you choose to keep nothing then any files on your system drive will be lost.  You should be aware that Windows does not entirely support moving the folders you have moved, so your likely going to run into problems, if you choose to keep nothing.

Comment: If you're worried, just disconnect any non-OS drives during the reinstall. And as always, before making any massive system changes, make a full backup.

Comment: If you keep nothing then you will have problems restoring your profile as it is now, because the new profile, will not be the same profile.  This means you would have to take ownership of your current profile folder, and of course, duplicate your current settings again.  You would be better off moving everything back to the system drive, doing the upgrade and keep everything, then moving stuff back where you want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you proceed with "Nothing" than it will delete all your settings and clear out all cookies, cache files, apps and many more settings.

While you want a clean installation so you should go ahead with "nothing". as it will not affect your other or secondary hard drive, it will only erase the primary partition where OS was installed.

With "Just Personal Files" options you can access your previous OS as it will create one folder "Windows.old folder" where all your C: drive is been stored.

You can use Backup data that will back up all your apps :

1) http://www.guidingtech.com/13926/backup-windows-8-apps-files-recimg/

2) https://www.maketecheasier.com/backup-app-data-in-windows-8/